# Read Database Name encoding in WSO2 Stream Integrator

Tags: wso2

I have wso2 si app using cdc

```
    @source(type = 'cdc', url = 'jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx:1433;databaseName=HCDB', username = "xxx", password = "xxxx", table.name = "dbo.xxxx", operation = "update", mode = "listening",@map(type = 'keyvalue'))
```

it is working fine but when I change the database name to production like this

```
    @source(type = 'cdc', url = 'jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx:1433;databaseName=HCDB-PRD', username = "xxx", password = "xxxx", table.name = "dbo.xxxx", operation = "update", mode = "listening",@map(type = 'keyvalue'))
```

it is only read the name before ((-))

database name = HCBD  >>>> fine

database name = HCBD-PRD >>>> read only until ((-))

I tried encoding ((-)) sign but it's not working.

any help will be appreciated